# How can I determine the block height on a certain day?

Tags: blockchain, height

Is there an easy calculator to determine the block height on a certain day?

i.e what was the block height on 14th October?

This was asked by JoeNakamoto on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/JoeNakamoto/status/1589590600818782210?s=20&t=QzU-Och8ZKxeLFPfNBd4cA).

There is a related question on converting block height to UNIX time [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/93919/how-to-create-block-height-to-unix-time-converter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is blockheightat.sh script included in my [bitcoin-scripts](https://github.com/kristapsk/bitcoin-scripts) (requires running Bitcoin Core). Examples:

```
$ ./blockheightat.sh 2022-10-14
758524
$ ./blockheightat.sh "2022-10-14 13:37"
758612
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a script [here](https://github.com/jsarenik/price.bublina.eu.org/blob/master/grepdate.sh) from jsarenik that does this.

You can run it like this:

```
$ ./grepdate.sh 2022-10-14 
758593
```

Alternatively there is a [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NiZFqp919BbWDwBLYs4k99LggnJdquVmSUjAfe-kUbA/) that seems to work.

Thanks to those on Twitter who answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can also estimate it like this:

```
h = (t-1213787930) / 596.066637
```

where `t` is the unix timestamp as stored in the block header.
And `h` is the block height.

These values were derived using a least-squares fitting over the last 160000 blocks.

Note that theoretically bitcoin attempts to make the factor close to `600`, but in practice the value of `600` is not reached.